# Pass a class name in AngularJS with ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have:

```
<tr ng-class="{{line.color}}" ng-repeat="line in gameRank | orderBy: sortType: sortReverse">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{line.username}}</td>
    <td>{{line.games}}</td>
    <td>{{line.winners}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I open debugger I see:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-class="BLUE" ng-repeat="line in gameRank | orderBy: sortType: sortReverse">
    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Admin</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
</tr>
```

So, my class `BLUE` is not applied to my element.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `ng-class="{{line.color}}"` --> `ng-class="line.color"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<tr ng-class="line.color" ...>
```

Instead of

```
<tr ng-class="{{line.color}}" ...>
```

### [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/nwjcj8w7/4/)